# Background images unexpectedly set to the descendant of the targeted div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to pass the css background-image multiple different children contained by the 'container' div through jQuery. It works however the  title is also affected unexpectedly. Here are the code:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='content'  id='museum'>
        <a>Detroit Museum High + Low</a>
    </div>
    <div class='content' id='metalic'>
        <a>Metalic Evolution</a>
    </div>
    <div class='content'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>

    <!--  smaller sections for loading content, projects, etc. -->

</div>
```

and js like this:

```
    for (var i = $('.container .content').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var $currentContent = $('.container :nth-child(' + i + ')');
        var $attr = $currentContent.attr('id');

        //filter out the content that doesn't have an id

        $currentContent.css({
            'background-image': typeof $attr === 'undefined' ? 'none' : 'url(_images/' + $currentContent.attr('id') + '.jpg)',
        });
    }
```

So the problem is that not only the 'content' divs have a background image, the Detroit and Evolution also have background image of the museum.jpg. I cannot figure out why...So any help will be very much appreciated!

Yong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because the `:nth-child` (note the space at the beginning) expression that you've written is effectively evaluating to `*:nth-child`, not `.content:nth-child` as you are expecting.

Comment: Got it. And it should be .content too. I am beening wasting an hour trying to figure out what is the issue... Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I was talking about my original code. I used `.container :nth-child`, but it really should be `.content:nth-child`.